# .json data to my mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, json

Can I load .json data file to my mysql workbench.
The .json data is too big, is it from Yelp dataset, i am working on a project in which i am using mysql, please if anyone have any idea please answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this directly. Unlike SQL, JSON isn't a tabular/relational format so you'd need to write script to parse the JSON and map each value of the JSON to a column in your MySQL database.